# Convert context free grammar to Syntax directed translation

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

```
P -> D ; E
P -> D ; D | id : T
T -> list of T | char | integer
E -> ( L ) | literal | num | id
L -> E , L | E
Write translation rules to determine the type of expressions ( E )
and lists ( L )
```

can anybody help me to write the translation rules? i don't really understand the first, second and last line of grammar.

Comment: The question is odd, because (a) translation rules don't normally "determine the type" of expressions, type inference rules do; and (b) there isn't enough information here to write either translation rules or type inference rules for this grammar.

Comment: Also, I suspect that the second line's left-hand-side should be 'D', not 'P'.